# Add product name to order number in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've searched for a solution to prefix my order number by the ordered product(s) name(s) or first letters.

I've tried to use a function on functions.php file to prefix my order number with the `woocommerce_order_number` filter but I can't get the product name in the order array (it's protected).

Is there a way to return this on my function using a loop for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function filter_woocommerce_order_number( $this_get_id, $instance ) { 
    $order = new WC_Order( $this_get_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $item['name']);;
        break;
    }
    $new_id = $product_name.'_'.$this_get_id;

    return $new_id; 
}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'filter_woocommerce_order_number', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've modified your function to get the last attribute of my product (color) to make it display order number like "red_1893" or "black_234" to make shipping easier.

`foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $kua = $item->get_meta_data();
        foreach ($kua as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
               $finalvalue = $value2;
            }
        }
    }
    $new_id = $finalvalue.'_'.$this_get_id; `